# apache camel not working with http ssl in xml

Tags: apache-camel

I tried the below code for making SSL connection:

```
<camel:sslContextParameters id="sslContextParameters">
<camel:keyManagers keyPassword="changeit">
    <camel:keyStore type="JKS" resource="C:\keystore.jks"
        password="changeit" />
</camel:keyManagers>
<camel:trustManagers>
    <camel:keyStore type="JKS" resource="C:\keystore.jks"
        password="changeit" />
</camel:trustManagers>
```

```
<to uri="https4://127.0.0.1/mail/?sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters"/>
```

But it is throwing SSLHandshakeException.

Comment: Please add stack trace to question via edit. What is exactly your question?

Comment: I believe only  some connectors honor the SSL context definition in the Camel context, it took me some time to search the camel mailing list to find it out which ones (I believe only the defaut http?). And even that depends on the camel version. I use mostly CXF, where it is possible to define the HTTP conduit .

Comment: could you provide the WHOLE handshake exception? As well - read it exactly what does it say